# echo variable inside DEFINE in php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to echo a variable inside a `DEFINE` function in my php page.

**I get the variable like so:**

```
$arr=file("myFile.txt");

foreach($arr as $str){
   list($token)=explode("|",$str);
}
```

**and then I echo it like so on the same page:**

```
echo $token;
```

up to this point everything works fine.

but I need to echo the `$token` inside a `DEFINE` on the same page like so:

```
DEFINE("AUTH_TOKEN", "'".$token."'");
```

I don't get any error at all but this doesn't work.

however, if i use:

```
DEFINE("AUTH_TOKEN", 'dghsa7dasdbhas8hdasdasod9a999');
```

it works just fine. the `dghsa7dasdbhas8hdasdasod9a999` is the value of `$token` *stored in the database*.

could someone please let me know if I'm missing something or doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

This is the entire code I am using:

```
// eBay site to use - 0 = United States
DEFINE("SITEID", 0);

// production vs. sandbox flag - true=production
DEFINE("FLAG_PRODUCTION", false);

// eBay Trading API version to use
DEFINE("API_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL", 779);

/* Set the Dev, App and Cert IDs
  Create these on developer.ebay.com
  check if need to use production or sandbox keys */
$arr = file("myFile.txt");

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    list($token) = explode("|", $str);
}

if (FLAG_PRODUCTION) {
    // PRODUCTION
    // Set the production URL for Trading API
    DEFINE("API_URL", 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll');

    // Set the auth token for the user profile used
    DEFINE("AUTH_TOKEN", 'YOUR_PRODUCTION_TOKEN');

} else {
    $arr = file("myFile.txt");
    foreach ($arr as $str) {
        list($token) = explode("|", $str);
    }
    echo $token;
    // SANDBOX
    // Set the sandbox URL for Trading API calls
    DEFINE("API_URL", 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll');

    // Set production credentials (from developer.ebay.com)
    // Set the auth token for the user profile used
    DEFINE("AUTH_TOKEN", "'" . $token . "'");
}
```

**the database is in a .txt file called `myFile.txt` and it looks like this:**

```
111111111111111|222222222222222222|3333333333333333333|4444444444444444444444
```

Comment: What does the first part have to do with the second part? Also why `"'".$token."'"` and not just `$token`? Why aren't you simply using `echo AUTH_TOKEN;`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This looks horribly convoluted.

Comment: try this `DEFINE("AUTH_TOKEN", $token);`

Comment: @IanLewis, what's convoluted about it? I simply want to echo the $token inside DEFINE!

Comment: Also you cannot redeclare a constant once it's defined. And there is no "echo inside DEFINE" here. That's at best string interpolation prior constant declaration.

Comment: @MehulJethloja, Thanks but i've already tried that and that didn't work either.

Comment: can you print_r the $token variable to ensure it's not an array?

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the issue, show how you echo it, etc.. This doesn't really make sense at the moment.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, please view my edit.

Comment: @user3716307 Where do you echo this value? `API_DEV_NAME`, etc. - that stuff all works? It's just the `AUTH_TOKEN` that does not? Can you make a smaller test case with only what's needed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @WesleyMurch, I echo the $token right above the line // SANDBOX. no, the `API_DEV_NAME` doesn't work either. its same as `AUTH_TOKEN`. i can echo them but I cannot get their value inside the DEFINE function!

Comment: @WesleyMurch, i've edited the question's sample code and made it smaller now. I hope that makes sense now?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DEFINE("AUTH_TOKEN", $token);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has a number of issues such as the repetition of $arr=file("myFile.txt"), however the crux of the question.

Move AUTH_TOKEN out of the if/else block and define it just after the foreach($arr as $str) loop (before the if/else)

This way you will be defining the AUTH_TOKEN once only and this will be far easier to debug.

```
$arr=file("myFile.txt");

foreach($arr as $str) {
   list($devName,$appName,$certName,$token)=explode("|",$str);
}

DEFINE('AUTH_TOKEN', $token);
```

Comment: not sure what this answer has to do? I don't really think its even worthy of the answer.